# C#: Reseting A Button or Going Back To A Previous Void

Tags: c#, winforms, button, timer

I have been trying multiple attempts to make this snippet of code work but I can't find a solution. Here it is:

```
   private void buttonTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sayingTwo.Visible = true;
        buttonTwo.Text = "Click To Hide Saying";
        buttonTwo.Click += new EventHandler(buttonTwo_Click2);
    }
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer tm2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    private void buttonTwo_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(sayingTwo.Visible == true)
        {
            buttonTwo .Enabled = false;
            sayingTwo.Visible = false;
            buttonTwo.Text = "Reactivating in 5 seconds";
            tm2.Interval = (1000);
            tm2.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick);
            tm2.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    int ii = 4;
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (ii != 0)
        {
            buttonTwo.Text = "Reactivating in " + ii + " seconds";
            ii -= 1;
        }
        if (ii == 0)
        {
            ii += 4;
            tm2.Enabled = false;
            buttonTwo.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Here is what the code will do so far: When the button is clicked a `saying/label` will appear. The name of the button will change to `"Click To Hide Saying"`. When it is clicked again, the label will disappear and the text will say `"Reactivating in (ii) seconds"` (ii is the time left on the reactivation).

What I want it to do is to go back to `buttonTwo_Click` Event when `ii = 0` (or when the button delay is up). If you have a solution to this problem or another way of doing it I would really appreciate it.

Comment: How about stopping the timer at the beginning of the `Tick` event handler and starting it again at the end?

Comment: @UweKeim I think the timer is the problem. It is the linking of the Event Handlers. Could this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tested and works.

```
    private string text;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        text = this.buttonTwo.Text;
    }


    private void buttonTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sayingTwo.Visible = true;
        buttonTwo.Text = "Click To Hide Saying";
        buttonTwo.Click -= buttonTwo_Click2;
        buttonTwo.Click += buttonTwo_Click2;
    }
    private void buttonTwo_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sayingTwo.Visible == true)
        {
            buttonTwo.Enabled = false;
            sayingTwo.Visible = false;
            buttonTwo.Text = "Reactivating in 5 seconds";
            tm2.Interval = 1000;
            buttonTwo.Click -= buttonTwo_Click2;
            tm2.Tick += timer2_Tick;
            tm2.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    int ii = 4;
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ii != 0)
        {
            buttonTwo.Text = "Reactivating in " + ii + " seconds";
            ii -= 1;
        }
        else
        {
            tm2.Enabled = false;
            tm2.Tick -= timer2_Tick;
            buttonTwo.Enabled = true;
            this.buttonTwo.Text = this.text;
            ii += 4;
        }
    }
```

Basically, you replace while with if as mentioned by the other answers.
Use variable to store your initial buttonTwo.Text as i suppose that is the text you want to appear on your button when resetting.

EDIT:
If you want multiple buttons with multiple labels and do not want to violate DRY, here is one solution:

```
    private Dictionary<Button, Label> correspondingControls;
    private Dictionary<Button, string> initialButtonInscriptions;

    private List<string> sayingsList;
    private Button currentButton;

    private int ii;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SerCorrespondingButtons();
        this.SetCorrespondingInitialButtonInscriptions();
    }

    private void SerCorrespondingButtons()
    {
        correspondingControls = new Dictionary<Button, Label>()
                                                                  {
            {this.buttonOne, this.sayingOne},
            {this.buttonTwo, this.sayingTwo},
                                                                  };
    }

    private void SetCorrespondingInitialButtonInscriptions()
    {
        this.initialButtonInscriptions = new Dictionary<Button, string>()
                                                                  {
            {this.buttonOne, this.buttonOne.Text},
            {this.buttonTwo, this.buttonTwo.Text}
                                                                  };
    }

    private void buttonTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        if (this.currentButton != null)
        {
            this.currentButton.Enabled = true;
            this.currentButton.Text = this.initialButtonInscriptions[this.currentButton];
            this.currentButton.Click += this.buttonTwo_Click;
            tm2.Enabled = false;
            tm2.Tick -= timer2_Tick;
        }

        this.currentButton = button;
        var saying = this.correspondingControls[button];
        saying.Visible = true;
        button.Text = "Click To Hide Saying";
        button.Click -= buttonTwo_Click;
        button.Click += buttonTwo_Click2;
    }
    private void buttonTwo_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        var saying = this.correspondingControls[button];
        saying.Visible = true;
        if (saying.Visible)
        {
            button.Enabled = false;
            saying.Visible = false;
            button.Text = "Reactivating in 5 seconds";
            tm2.Interval = 1000;
            button.Click -= buttonTwo_Click2;
            button.Click += buttonTwo_Click;
            this.ii = 4;
            tm2.Tick += timer2_Tick;
            tm2.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ii != 0)
        {
            this.currentButton.Text = "Reactivating in " + ii + " seconds";
            ii -= 1;
        }
    }
```

Tested and works.

Comment: Do I have to do this for every button?

Comment: For how i see it the answer is yes, if you do not use custom events. The reason for this is, that you can not use extension methods because you have three class instances in buttonTwo_Click body, not one.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for the replies. I am now more informed.

Comment: Actually, it can be done without custom events. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you for the effort you put into this. I appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

For ease and reusability, take the actual work out of the event and put it in a function. This can be then used by the event and when the timer hits 0

Edit: You had a While instead of an If too.

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tm2.Interval = 1000;
    tm2.Tick += timer2_Tick;
}

private void buttonTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoClickWork();
}
System.Windows.Forms.Timer tm2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();


private void DoClickWork()
{
    buttonTwo.Text = "Reactivating in 5 seconds";
    buttonTwo.Enabled = false;
    tm2.Enabled = true;
    sayingTwo.Visible = false;

}
int ii = 4;
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ii != 0)
    {
        ii -= 1;
        buttonTwo.Text = "Reactivating in " + ii + " seconds";
    }
    if (ii == 0)
    {
        ii += 4;
        tm2.Enabled = false;
        buttonTwo.Enabled = true;
        buttonTwo.Text = "Click To Hide Saying";
        sayingTwo.Visible = true;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for showing me this. This is for a class assignment and I searched up everything I could.